# movl multi-data instruction and assembly optimization comparison

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly, llvm, disassembly

Consider a simple loop in :

```
for(int i=0;i<32;i++) 
    a[i] = i;
```

The LLVM disassembler shows the following assembly:

```
.LBB0_1:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
movl    %eax, (%esp,%eax,4)
addl    $1, %eax
adcl    $0, %ecx
cmpl    $32, %eax
jne .LBB0_1
# BB#2:
xorl    %eax, %eax
addl    $140, %esp
ret
```

**Question 1:** Can anyone explain `movl    %eax, (%esp,%eax,4)` instruction?

Moreover, Visual Studio disassembler outputs the following assembly:

```
    ;for(int i=0;i<32;i++)
00F290B5  mov         dword ptr [ebp-94h],0  
00F290BF  jmp         main+60h (0F290D0h)  
00F290C1  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-94h]  
00F290C7  add         eax,1  
00F290CA  mov         dword ptr [ebp-94h],eax  
00F290D0  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-94h],20h  
00F290D7  jge         main+7Eh (0F290EEh)  
        ;a[i] = i;
00F290D9  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-94h]  
00F290DF  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-94h]  
00F290E5  mov         dword ptr a[eax*4],ecx  
00F290EC  jmp         main+51h (0F290C1h)  
    ;return 0;
00F290EE  xor         eax,eax
```

Obvoiusly the LLVM's output is more optimized.

**Question 2:** Is there an option in Visual Studio to optimize the code like LLVM does?

**Update:**

Results after setting Solution Configurations to Release & Optimization to Full Optimization(/Ox):

```
;   int a[32] = {0};
;   for(int i=0;i<32;i++)
 0039128B  xor         eax,eax  
 0039128D  lea         ecx,[a]  
 00391293  movd        xmm0,eax  
 00391297  pshufd      xmm0,xmm0,0  
 0039129C  paddd       xmm0,xmm1  
 003912A0  add         eax,4  
;   {
;       a[i] = i;
 003912A3  movdqu      xmmword ptr [ecx],xmm0  
 003912A7  lea         ecx,[ecx+10h]  
 003912AA  cmp         eax,20h  
 003912AD  jl          main+23h (0391293h)  
;   }
;   return 0;
; };
 003912AF  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-4]  
 003912B2  xor         ecx,ebp  
 003912B4  xor         eax,eax  
 003912B6  call        __security_check_cookie (03916FDh)  
 003912BB  mov         esp,ebp  
 003912BD  pop         ebp  
 003912BE  ret
```

Comment: Are optimizations even on in your Visual Studio build?

Comment: @Mysticial, can you please explain how can I enable optimizations in Visual Studio IDE?

Comment: Just change the build mode from `Debug` to `Release`. That will do it. It should be in one of the toolbars at the top.

Comment: Yeah, I highly suspect that you're compiling for `Debug` which has no optimizations. In `Release`, it should look a lot better. If that's the case, then I'll make an answer.

Comment: @Mysticial: yes -- with optimization turned on, if you don't use the array it'll just produce `xor eax, eax/label:inc eax/cmp eax,32/jnz label` (i.e., since you're not using the array, it doesn't even create it -- not sure why it leaves the loop there at all).

Comment: @JerryCoffin [DCE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code_elimination) FTW! I think completely eliminating the loop would take multiple DCE passses to accomplish. Most (normal) code probably won't have this kind of avalanche of dead-code that can be eliminated. So the compiler probably doesn't bother to keep iterating it.

Comment: @Mysticial: Probably. If you put it in a function outside `main`, it produces the (worthless) function, but eliminates the call to it.

Comment: @JerryCoffin That's probably because it sees that the function has no external effects. I suppose it's easier to prove that instead of iterating (potentially expensive) DCE passes. Dunno, only MS knows their optimizer. haha

Comment: Oh AT&T syntax, how you suck so

Comment: @Mysticial, perhaps an elementary question: how can I see the assembly generated when Release is set in Solution Configurations?

Comment: Right click on your project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Output Files -> Assembler Output

Comment: Ha! You must be using VS2012. Your update shows that it got vectorized!

Comment: @Mysticial, Yup VS2012 RC. BTW I am showing the output of Disassembler during the debug (under release mode). In asm file under Release directory, it has same instructions but it looks little untidy like `lea ecx, DWORD PTR _a$[ebp]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`movl %eax, (%esp,%eax,4)` is just an indirect memory store.

It stores `%eax` into the memory location: `%esp + %eax * 4`. In this case:

- `%esp` is the array `a`.
- `%eax` is the index `i`.
- `4` is the size of `int`.

---

For your second question, the code output by Visual Studio looks like it was done without optimizations. There's a lot of excessive memory loads and stores.

For example: `dword ptr [ebp-94h]` appears to be the index `i` variable. But without optimizations, it never got promoted to a register.

Enable optimizations, and you will see that it will produce much more sane code.

Comment: Check the updates. I set optimization to `Full optimization (/Ox)`. After building assembly in Release, the code consists of 17 lines vs. 12 lines of VS Debug mode vs. 7 lines of LLVM... Its getting worse. Is there a better way to optimize instructions in VS?

Comment: Actually, it's about as good as it gets. It got vectorized. So the loop is doing 4 iterations at once. (Note the: `add eax,4`) I can (probably) do a bit better than that. But yes, it's optimized, very well too.

Comment: Thanks I didn't realized that getting vectorized instruction implies victory ... For sake of argument, is there anything we can infer from LLVM's assembly which can optimize this code a even better? Any hints? :-)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but the assembly generated by LLVM actually has a useless instruction. `adcl $0, %ecx` can be deleted. It doesn't do anything.

Comment: That's correct. So I accept it as answer. Thanks for your kind help. :)